# Setting Controls to enabled false If they are not visible

Tags: c#

Hi What I would like to accomplish is 
When I change the visible property of a control to false I also want to change the enabled property to false. and vice versa.

the scenario is(assuming we have a textbox and checkbox this:
if the checkbox is checked the textbox is visible and enabled
else
textbox is not visible and not enabled

I can do this through the events but it's too much code to repeat when have multiple controls..

Comment: Loop through your controls upon startup and add the same VisibilityChanged hook to each control which sets enabled to false or true.

Answer (score 1):

You could handle the control's [`VisibleChanged`-event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visiblechanged(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
void Controls_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Control c = (Control) sender;
   c.Enabled = c.Visible;
}
```

You can use the same event-handler for all controls. For example in the constructor:

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    c.VisibleChanged += new EventHandler(this.Controls_VisibleChanged);
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand your question but I'll write something that might help.

Double click on your checkbox and edit the `CheckedChanged` event and write the code:

```
if (!<CheckBoxName>.Checked)
{
    <TextBoxName>.Enabled = false;
    <TextBoxName>.Hide();
}
else
{
    <TextBoxName>.Enabled = true;
    <TextBoxName>.Show();
}
```

Note:
`<CheckBoxName>`= Your checkBox name
`<TextBoxName>`= Your TextBox name

Change the CheckBox.Checked properties and change it to `true` to make the code running smoothly.
I hope that helps you...